# ISO 8601 Date format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

Can I get DateTime.Now to be formatted to

```
2010-03-01T00:00:00Z
```

I have used this to format the date part

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(3001, 0, 0, 0)).GetDateTimeFormats()[5]
```

Answer (score 14):

All the following examples assume that local time is London time and it is 5:11pm on the 11th June 2009.

If you want full ISO 8601 format you can use:

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")
// Gives 2009-06-11T16:11:10.5312500Z
```

Or this if you want to specify a time zone offset:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o")
// Gives 2009-06-11T17:11:10.5312500+0100
```

If you don't want the fraction of a second you can use this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("s") + "Z"
// Gives 2009-06-11T16:11:10Z
```

or:

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK")
// Also gives 2009-06-11T16:11:10Z
```

**Note that the following is wrong** as it gives the local time as though it is UTC time which is only true if you are somewhere like London and it is the middle of winter:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
// Gives 2009-06-11T17:11:10Z which is wrong as it is an hour out.
```

Comment: So what does the K in ":ssK" mean? I cannot find any documentation about that. Not in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx, nor in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx, nor with a Google search for "DataTime ToString 'ssK'"

Comment: K is for "Time Zone Information". The documentation is on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx or for the specific part of that page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier

Answer (score 4):

Yes if you use ToString, have a look at the MSDN page for datetime formatting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Very simple, just use a format string that fits your requirements:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
'2009-06-11T16:26:47Z'
```

Comment: Ahh, didn't know about "ToUniversalTime". That's cool. AFAIK the end result here is the same as just doing. DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(YOUR_FORMAT). That is: DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() == DateTime.UtcNow.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want this:

```
 XmlConvert.ToString(yourdate)
```

Comment: This gives the same as .ToString("o") which could be 2009-06-11T17:11:10.5312500+0100 which may or may not be what the OP wanted.

Comment: If you wanted to force UTC you could use this XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(3001, 0, 0, 0)).ToString("s");
```

[Heres a list of ways to format a string](http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Comment: This does not put the Z at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For all your C# string/date formatting needs: http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/

I see:

```
s   Sortable date string    2002-12-10T22:11:29
u   Universal sortable, local time  2002-12-10 22:13:50Z
```

But given the options on the page you can construct the precise format manually.